# Tensorflow tf.dataset.shuffle very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am training a VAE model with 9100 images (each of size 256 x 64). I train the model with Nvidia RTX 3080. First, I load all the images into a numpy array of size 9100 x 256 x 64 called `traindata`. Then, to form a dataset for training, I use

```
train_dataset = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(traindata).shuffle(len(traindata)).batch(batch_size))
```

Here I use a `batch_size` of 65. I mainly have 2 questions about the things that I see during training:

### Question 1:

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle), the whole dataset is being re-shuffled for every epoch. However, the training is very slow in this way (around 50 seconds per epoch). I did a comparison with a training without shuffle by not calling `.shuffle(len(traindata))` when creating the dataset, and the training is much faster (around 20s/epoch). I am wondering why the `.shuffle()` operation is so slow and if there's any methods to make it faster? According to [this StatsSE thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245502/why-should-we-shuffle-data-while-training-a-neural-network), shuffling is quite important for training and that's why I include the shuffle operation.

### Question 2:

When I called `.shuffle()` when creating the dataset, Tensorflow always gives the following message

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/windows/subprocess.cc:308] SubProcess ended with return code: 4294967295
```

I try to search online but still cannot understand the meaning behind this. Does this mean there's some error or it's just a warning that I can ignore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because holding all elements of your dataset in the buffer is expensive. Unless you absolutely need perfect randomness, you should use a smaller `buffer_size`. All elements will eventually be taken, but in a more deterministic manner.

This is what's going to happen with a smaller `buffer_size`, say 3. The buffer is the brackets, and Tensorflow samples a random value in this bracket. The one randomly picked is `^`

```
1) [1 2 3]4 5 6 7 8 9 
      ^
2) [1 3 4]5 6 7 8
        ^
3) [1 3 5]6 7 8
        ^
4) [1 3 6]7 8
    ^
5) [3 6 7]8
```

Etc

So, earlier values will be taken earlier in your epoch, but you will still have some shuffling done, and all samples will eventually be taken.

**tl;dr** reduce `buffer_size` by *a lot*