# What determines when a tensrflow.data.Dataset.shuffle needs to fill up its shuffle buffer

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow code that creates the following data pipeline:

```
# Defining the positive and negative paths
POS = os.path.join('data',ship_type[0],hphone,btype[0],'audio_segments_subset', '*.mp3')
NEG = os.path.join('data',ship_type[1],hphone,btype[1],'audio_segments_subset', '*.mp3')

# Creating the Datasets
pos = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(POS).shuffle(len(POS),seed=189)
neg = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(NEG).shuffle(len(NEG),seed=189)

pos0 = pos.take(1000)
neg0 = neg.take(1000)

# Adding labels
positives = tf.data.Dataset.zip((pos0, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.ones(len(pos0)))))
negatives = tf.data.Dataset.zip((neg0, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.zeros(len(neg0)))))
data_init = positives.concatenate(negatives)

# Creating a Tensorflow Data Pipeline
data = data_init.map(preprocess)
data = data.cache()
data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=2000)
data = data.batch(16)
data = data.prefetch(8)

# Split into Training and Testing Partitions
train = data.take(36)
test = data.skip(36).take(15)
```

As I understand this pipeline, it takes mp3 files from 2 different directories with positive and negative examples, shuffles the order of the files, and then takes 1000 positive and negative examples, each. These samples are then concatenated into `data_init`.

The data pipeline then involves running each file through the `preprocess` function (Not shown, but basically puts file data into a tfio.audio tensor); caching the data; shuffling it; defining a batch size and how many batches to prefetch. After this, the first 36 batches become the training set and the next 15 (i.e. 36-51) become the test set.

When I train using the command:

```
hist=model.fit(train, epochs=40, validation_data=test)
```

I find that during the first epoch, I get a series of the following log messages:

```
I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:422] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): xxx of yyy
```

This makes sense. The pipeline is placing data into a buffer, which it then shuffles. What I don't understand is what determines when the shuffle buffer needs to be filled.

When the `buffer size=1000`, it needs to be refilled at each training step and each evaluation. At `buffer size=1500`, it only needs to be filled for the first training epoch, but not for the first evaluation or at any time afterwards. At `buffer size=1250`, it only needs to be filled for the first training epoch and evaluation, but not thereafter.

Can anyone explain this behavior? I could understand always refilling the buffer at the start of an epoch, only refilling on the epochs where the buffer is too small for both the train & validation set, or never refilling. I don't see what the cause is of the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: it's basically putting `BUFFER_SIZE` elements in memory, and takes `BATCH_SIZE` randomly in this buffer. then it replaces these by the next `BATCH_SIZE` elements in your dataset. btw I think there might be a leak between train and test

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67839368/10908375

Comment: @NicolasGervais - I'm also trying to convince myself that there is no leak between train & test, which is why I'm trying to understand this odd behavior. Why should a buffer size of 1000 need to be refilled for every one of 10 epochs, while a buffer size of 1500 never needs to be refilled?

Comment: the buffer is filled at every batch

Comment: @NicolasGervais - If it refills at every batch, why don't I see the same message, regardless of buffer size. If it only refills after the buffer has been exhausted, why does the buffer size of 1000 need to be refilled on each of 10 epochs, but the buffer size of 1500 only needs to be filled upon the first epoch?